# Apache-specific md5 javascript impelementation for .htpsswrd

Tags: javascript, apache, hash

I'm trying to save a username and password combo in a .htpsswrd file. Before I would send the username/password to the server to be saved by a php script, I would like to hash the password in MD5, so the plain password will not travel over http... 
I have found a script, which will generate me an MD5 hash in javascript, but it is not accepted by the apache server as a valid password.
Here is what I'm always getting:

```
password: a
hash: 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
```

What it should look like:

```
password: a
hash: $apr1$OcckEo.t$ohO2NxaQZm/YAcWfFZSLi.
```

This site: http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html tells me, that the hash is made up from: Apache-specific algorithm using an iterated (1,000 times) MD5 digest of various combinations of a random salt and the password. This is the default (since Apache version 2.2.18).

All I would need, to have a function, that will hash me any string, and return the properly hashed reply.
And this is where I'm stuck! Anyone? :)

Answer (score 1):

Well two points:

1-[This Library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) might help with what you are trying to do.

2-My recommendation is to postpone the md5 to the server side script along with the salt. On the client side base64 encode the pass along with your own string operations if you wish (and make sure not to name the input name to password).
I always liked this method simply because it will be a pain in the ass for whoever that is trying to sniff around plus I can handle the passwords as I like server side with any further operations.

Good luck my friend

Comment: Thanks. I don't really see how can I make a pain in the ass by encoding in base64... but I understand that, it will be much easier to do whatever I want on the server... :D

Comment: The pain in the ass is when they will decode the variable and find it unusable since you did your own string operations on it.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by string operations? (me == noob) :)

Comment: The password that will be entered will be a string (a bunch of characters).So you can put a function in your javascript that will work on this string (your own formulas and such) so it will perform some kind of encryption before the base64. I keep it simple and fun.Then the fun decryption is done server side then voila...you got your pass ready to be cooked